# Visual Studio search and replace within subfolders

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to search only a subset of folders in visual studio?  I would like to find all instances of

`console.log` in my code.  But, I don't want to search 3rd party *.js files.

Comment: For future reference, there are some good explanations on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of Visual Studio, but I always keep a copy of Notepad++ handy when searching for something in multiple files. Are your 3rd party javascripts all contained in a vendor folder or something? If you're not doing tier 3 development, move the javascript folder off to your desktop or something, perform the search/replace and then move the folder back.

Answer (score 9):

This functionality was requested as a feature addition to Visual Studio and can be seen in [this Microsoft Connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/589924/visual-studio-easy-find-and-replace-in-folder).

Unfortunately, the issue was closed as "Won't Fix", but a few workarounds exist (albeit with a few more steps required):

Perform the steps listed as the workaround within the Microsoft Connect issue:

> *Although VS doesn't currently have a context menu item for 'search only in this folder,' it is possible to scope your Find and Replace
>   searches to a given folder. To do this, bring up the Find dialog,
>   choose Find In Files or Replace in Files (not Quick Find or Quick
>   Replace), and click on the '...' button next to the "Look in:"
>   dropdown. This should bring up another dialog that allows you to
>   choose a specific folder or set of folders for your search.*

Or do what I do, which is very similar:

- Right-click on the folder you wish to search in.
- Select the "Open Folder in File Explorer" option which opens Windows Explorer at the
  specified location.
- Copy the full path from Windows Explorer's title bar to your clipboard, then close Windows Explorer.
- Back in Visual Studio, open up the Find & Replace dialog, and paste in the copied
  path to the "Look in:" textbox in the dialog.

Comment: +1 Even if there are a couple of steps to achieve the goal, it's look like a good solution considering that we usually not searching by folder 100 times a day.

Comment: I started using this workaround.  Unfortunately, VS remembers your path from previous sessions, even when you have opened an entirely different solution.  I had 2 different versions of the same solution on disk, and was searching and modifying the wrong one.  T.T

Answer (score 1):

In notepad++ you must open all files.
An alternative would be Windows Grep (http://www.wingrep.com/)
You can replace in all files in a subset of extension using regular expression.